# How to apply circulary symmetric gaussian convolution in spatial domain?

Tags: c++, image-processing, fft

I am trying to implement the "dodging-and-burning" using reinhard local operator. The paper that I am trying to implement: https://www.cis.rit.edu/people/faculty/ferwerda/publications/sig02_paper.pdf

I am now stuck at the convolution step in Equation 6. The authors suggest that the convolution can be done in the Fourier domain but also in spatial domain. I am interested in the spatial domain since that easier but it is not clear to me how to tackle that in C++ code and what it means to do it in the spatial domain. So is it just applying bilateral filter using gaussian on the each luminance pixel value or would that not work in the context of the paper?

Comment: A bilateral filter is a non-linear filter, and therefore cannot be applied through the Fourier domain. The paper talks about a Gaussian filter, which is a linear filter, and not the same as a bilateral filter. You should be using a library to apply these filters to your image. Don't reinvent the wheel, you'll do lots of work, and make lots of mistakes, and you'll just be wasting time. People put out libraries with correct, tested functionality so that you can skip all that wasting of time.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I can make use of a library but I want to learn how convolution works by implementing them since I am new to image processing. Do you have any suggestions on how to tackle the steps given in the paper to convolve the luminance with gaussian linear filter in different scales?

Comment: If you want to learn image processing, start with a book in the field. Implementing things you see in the scientific literature is a very hard way to learn. If you're scared of books, you can always Google for tutorials. The first two hits for "Gaussian filter" are [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_filter) and [HIRP2](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/gsmooth.htm), both good resources.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the resources Cris I will definitely check them out. I only have couple more questions related to the paper though if you don't mind:

1- V(x,y,s) is the result of convolving the Gauss filter with luminance values for different scales. However, what does a "scale" given by letter "s" mean in V(x,y,s). Should I preceive it as the standard deviation of the Gauss filter?

2- In the paper, R_i(x,y,s) and V_i(x,y,s) are shown. What I don't understand is, what does "i" represent in the equations?

3- what kernel size should I use for the Gaussian filter?